# How to display several subcategories and their news in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a news site and I am trying to include a block of news in it.

see the image please

[image]

I created a category call **world news** and added subcategories. (Travel, News, Art, Bussines)

I display them one by one, I mean I do a query for each news, that means 4 different queries like below :

```
$sql = "SELECT posts.post_catId,
    posts.post_seo_url,
    posts.post_desc,
    posts.post_type,
    posts.post_status,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_image_url,
    categories.catId,
    categories.catName,
    categories.cat_seo_url
    FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN categories
    ON posts.post_catId = categories.catId 
    WHERE post_catId = catId AND cat_seo_url = 'art'
    AND post_status = ?
    ORDER BY post_created_at DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['1',]);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     //here
    }
}
```

My question is: **is there a way to display them in one query ?**

Edit : I want to display 1 news from 4 specific categories with one query instead of 4.

I know I can add a new row to categories table to secify which categories can be displayed.

Comment: If you remove the `AND cat_seo_url = 'art' ` it'll return stories for all the categories. Algo, the `WHERE post_catId = catId` line is superfluous since you already set that constraint in the join.

Comment: I have to display 4 categories  and 1 news for each category, your example will display all categories and if I limit them to 4 then it will display random categories not specified categories. thanks for warn of where clause.

Comment: What is the primary id for the `posts` table? I'm guessing `postId`?

Comment: This is posts table where I add category id 'post_catId' and in the categories table is 'catId'

Comment: I thought `post_catId` is the category id (the foreign key) in the `posts` table? I'm talking about the primary key. At second glance, it seems that `post_seo_url` seems to be the primary key, or at least can act like one since it's unique.

Comment: If you want to specify which categories that you are querying for, you may use an `IN` statement

Comment: @MatthewAnderson categories names are in picture.

Comment: Assign a `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned on each category with descending order by and only return news from each category that get row number = 1

Answer (score 0):

You 'invert' the query, selecting the categories first and then joining to the posts table, constraining it by the `post_seo_url` field, like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    categories.catId,
    categories.catName,
    categories.cat_seo_url,
    posts.post_catId,
    posts.post_seo_url,
    posts.post_desc,
    posts.post_type,
    posts.post_status,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_image_url,
    FROM categories
    JOIN posts ON posts.post_seo_url = (
       SELECT p.post_seo_url FROM posts as p
       WHERE categories.catId = p.post_catId
       ORDER BY p.post_created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    )
    WHERE post_status = ?"
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my question, I dont have a problem with my query. What I asked was : İf its possible to display news in seperate categories in one query. same as in picture. in your way I have to do 4 queries.

Comment: That query selects one story for each category, which is what you want.

Comment: I want to display 1 news from 4 specified categories, that is what I asked in question. thanks

Comment: But that's what the query does. It selects all the categories that are in the database and then select one story per category. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT p.*,
       categories.catId,
       categories.catName,
       categories.cat_seo_url
   FROM
    (SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY posts.post_catId ORDER BY posts.post_created_at DESC) AS RN,
    posts.post_catId,
    posts.post_seo_url,
    posts.post_desc,
    posts.post_type,
    posts.post_status,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_image_url
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_status = ? ) p 
    JOIN categories
    ON p.post_catId = categories.catId 
    WHERE RN=1;
```

I've made the query on `posts` table to become a subquery with addition of `ROW_NUMBER()` function then `JOIN` it with `categories` table and added `WHERE` that only return row number = 1. I've changed the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` because I don't see any reason to use `LEFT JOIN` in this operation. However, if there is a reason, please update it in your question.

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fdc1ffb74dc3feea0561ed19ebdde7f)

Comment: query part is fine, so how to display posts same as in picture ? just do while loop ? will it display 4 secific categories for example: Travel, News, business, Art. this will display random posts and random categories. I was think to add a row to categories table to secify which categories can be displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure how in PHP but for an idea, I've did a few html with `node.js+ejs` before and what I did was I created a html table on the front end with 4 horizontal cells. On each cells I'll do an `if` operation. So for example, in `ejs` the code will be something like `<% query1.forEach((query1, index) => { %><% if (query1.catId == "1") {%><td><%= query1.catName%><br><%= query1.post_title%><br><%= query1.post_desc%></td>
    <% } else { %> <td></td> `

Comment: Basically, on cell 1, I'll check `if` the `catid=1` then return the values that I want where `else` I'll return empty cell then repeat the same checking on cell 2,3 & 4. That's just an example base on my previous projects though.

Comment: that seems to much work lol. I will add a new row to categories table and set value 1 and then display specific categories with one query. thanks for the answer. ı  upvoted it.